# All range slider libraries giving the error Element type invalid. What else can I try?

Tags: reactjs, slider, rangeslider, mdbreact

I want to create a slider in my project and I am using react-rangeslider library. I wrote a very simple piece

```
const Slider = require('react-rangeslider');
var Para = React.createClass({
handleChange: function(value) {
        this.setState({
            value: value,
        });
    },
    render: function () {

        return (
            <Slider
        value={this.state.value}
        orientation="vertical"
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
        );
    }
});
```

which is resulting in the error

```
app.js:6873 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Para`.
```

Version `"react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0"`
Other libraries I tried were mdbReact, ReactBootstrapSlider.

I did see the posts with similar error but all those are importing in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, the library doesn't export default properly, so to import the library you'll need to do:

```
const Slider = required('react-rangeslider').default;
```

Source:
https://github.com/whoisandy/react-rangeslider/issues/96

Answer (score 0):

this error happens when you import incorrectly your component.

**in case you are using default export:**

```
// yourfile.js
const Component;
export default Component;
```

```
// anotherFile.js
import yourComponent form './yourfile';
```

**in case you are using named export:**

```
// yourfile.js
export const Component;
```

```
// anotherFile.js
import { Component } form './yourfile';
```